# agent.add() is not working sometimes when intent is having a big logic and the api call using Axios

Tags: node.js, axios, dialogflow-es

I am having few intents in my dialogflow agent for which I have written function using the inline editor of Dialogflow so in few intents, I am calling some APIS using Axios with some kind of logic and for this such intent, it is not able to prompt message on test console sometimes but easily printing logs in the console.

I am attaching some dummy code -:

```
function someintent(agent){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Tried using promises as well but didn't work
    const parameter1 = agent.parameters.parameter1;
    const parameter2 = agent.parameters.parameter2;

    // Some of the code is just logic, Problem mainly occurs at line no 39

    if (parameter1 != ''){  



        if (parameter1.toString().length !=9){

            agent.add('Please enter valid 9 digit number');
            agent.context.set({
            'name':'someintent-followup',
            'lifespan': 0
            });

        }

        else{

            if(isNaN(parameter1)){

                agent.add('Please enter integer');
                agent.context.set({
                'name':'previous-followup'
                });
            }


            /**
             * Main area which creates problem is below code.
             * 
             */

            else{

                agent.add('What is the nature of your Business ?'); // This is not working sometimes

                return axios.post('http://some-test-api/',
                    {"parameters1": parameter1}).then((result) => {
                        console.log(result.data);
                        console.log('Store data to api');
                          //agent.add('What is the nature of your Business ?'); // I tried here also which is also not working sometimes



                });

            }
        }
    }

    else{


          agent.add('What is the nature of your Business ?');
          return axios.post('http://some-test-api/',
                    {"parameters2": parameter2}).then((result) => {
                        console.log(result.data);
                        console.log('Store data to api');



                });

    }


    resolve(); // Resolving promise
}
```

As per my understanding, the issue is if the intent is having a quite big logic and that too with some API Call then it has timeout and callback function issue (maybe) which creates a problem of not printing response in the interface(test console)

I really required help with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are two potential issues you have:

The first is that it sounds like you're concerned that the async call with axios will take "too long". This may be a concern if the call plus your other processing takes more than a few seconds.

But what looks more likely is that how you're making your call with axios and using Promises is causing an issue.

With the code you're showing, you're returning the new Promise object, but in the execution code you're returning the axios Promise, so the call to `resolve()` never gets made. You should only be calling `resolve()` when the async operation has, itself, resolved.

But since `axios.post()` returns a Promise, you don't need to wrap it in your own Promise. You just need to return the Promise/then chain that is part of each axios call.

So your code might look something like (untested):

```
function someintent(agent){

    const parameter1 = agent.parameters.parameter1;
    const parameter2 = agent.parameters.parameter2;

    if (parameter1 != ''){  
        if (parameter1.toString().length !=9){
            agent.add('Please enter valid 9 digit number');
            agent.context.set({
            'name':'someintent-followup',
            'lifespan': 0
            });
        }else{
            if(isNaN(parameter1)){
                agent.add('Please enter integer');
                agent.context.set({
                'name':'previous-followup'
                });
            }else{
                return axios.post('http://some-test-api/',{"parameters1": parameter1})
                    .then((result) => {
                        console.log(result.data);
                        console.log('Store data to api');
                        agent.add('What is the nature of your Business ?');
                    });
            }
        }
    }else{
          return axios.post('http://some-test-api/',{"parameters2": parameter2})
              .then((result) => {
                   console.log(result.data);
                   console.log('Store data to api');
                   agent.add('What is the nature of your Business ?');
               });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response but the code you writes here, I wrote it like that only previously but it was not working that's the reason I thought of making a promise object and make a resolve.

If you could suggest something is highly appreciated.
As I was going through some of the Github issues and StackOverflow, I came to know the concept of promises. I am not able to get an optimal solution.

Link for the same kind of issue on Github may help -: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/86